# What does "class MyClass : public X" mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I have seen this many times and I can't describe it well enough to google search it:

What is the difference between "Foo" and "Bar" in the following code sample?

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(){}
    ~Base(){}
};

class Foo : Base {

};

class Bar : public Base {

};
```

What is this distinction called?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1563765

Comment: I'd just search for something like "c++ public base class"

Comment: This is called "inheritance", details can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks that's exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Duplicate of [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

The answer is that it is called "public base class".